# how to set system property in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, vert.x

I have a requirement to set system property in spring boot application.
I don't want to set it from command line.

My concern is what is the best practice to do it.
Either from constructor 
Or inside main method. Below is sample for setting it from constructor

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Sample{
@Autowired
protected TempInfoDao tempInfoDao;

public Sample{
   //Setting System property inside constructor
    System.setProperty("vertx.hazelcast.config","./config/cluster.xml");
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Sample.class, args);
}
```

}

What is best approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not good idea to set system variables from inside Java code.
Basically, variables are meant to keep the code free from having any variable values.

Use properties files to store your configurations. Spring Boot does a great job externalising your configurations.
It also let to you have environmental configurations in separate files and does a great job initialising it.

Refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: "Use properties files to store your configurations". Excellent advice. And now, if you want to write a correct answer in SO, you must give an explanation and example, how to do it. Even the exact reference is not enough, according to rules. And such misty reference to a huge chapter of the Spring docs looks like a very bad joke. BTW, if the Spring docs were of some acceptable quality, we won't need to ask here about the subj. Any references are only additions to YOUR answer.

Comment: Looks like YOU are CONFUSED with the question. The question is not specific to any problem, error, and not even its a type of my code isn't working question. The OP is well aware of what he/her is doing. The answer precisely provides what is needed. That is why the OP is satisfied with the answer and also accepted the answer.

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." - end of citation

Comment: It was useful to me but does not answer the question: how to set system property.

Comment: I also do not understand how this answers the question being asked. Note that the question is about how to set a Java system property, likely something read by a non-Spring component (in the code example, `vertx.hazelcast.config`). The reference provided is about the various sources for providing configuration to Spring beans.

Comment: I cannot see how this answers the question, and have exactly the same critique as @skagedal. A general "don't do this", while not showing what to do is unhelpful. If you place the hazelcast value somewhere in the spring config, you still need to _set_ it using your own code, as Spring does not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Setting System properties in constructor is not a good approach.

You could use a separate class and spring annotations to do that like below.

```java
@Profile("production")
@Component
public class ProductionPropertySetter {
    @PostConstruct
    public void setProperty() {
       System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", 15);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should base your Sample class on a special class, written by you. I propose the name BaseSettingProperties

```
public class TestBaseWithProperties extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    {
         System.setProperty("name.of.property", "value/of/property");
    }
}
```

This way you can guarantee that properties would be set really ***before*** all reading the context and wiring. And you can surely use these properties even in `include`d XMLs.

It is possible to set variables in beans, by putting properties in some file.of.needed.properties and using it

```
<bean id="prop" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="file.of.needed.properties" />
</bean>
```

, but you cannot guarantee the order of property setting and `include` calling. Because it is not calling but physical including. And you cannot set dependency of `include` on the properties setting bean - I found no syntax for that :-(. On the other hand, yes, I use the very old Spring of 3rd version, but I couldn't find a solution in the recent internet.